# CS0116 C# Um namespace não pode conter diretamente membros, como campos ou métodos

Tags: c#

Boa tarde, estou usando o VS17 C# e copiei o comando de outro projeto e está dando erro:

```
CS0116  C# Um namespace não pode conter diretamente membros, como campos ou métodos
```

linha do erro:

```
public static DataTable EmpresaPesquisar(global::CamadaModelos.mdlEmpresa _mdlEmpresa)
```

tentei esse:

```
public static DataTable EmpresaPesquisar(CamadaModelos.mdlEmpresa _mdlEmpresa)
```

Comment: Pelo que está escrito, está faltando a classe dos métodos.

Comment: poderia detalhar um pouco mais ? 
sou novo e não tenho tanta experiencia assim.

Answer (score 5):

Tudo dentro de um projeto deve estar contido numa classe. Visto, talvez esse seja o problema. Envolva seus métodos, propriedades e variáveis todas em uma classe.

Comment: Quando você tira o global:: qual erro da?

Comment: estava fora das " } " ... :(

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu a resolução :D

Comment: Provavelmente era o "}" da classe/namespace. Que bom que conseguiu resolver o problema.

Comment: Sim, como dito na resposta, tudo dentro do projeto, seja uma tela, um windows forms, etc. fica dentro de uma classe. Sim, exatamente tudo. E se algo ficar fora dela, provavelmente dará um erro.