# Onde esta o erro neste metodo?

Tags: c#

```
public DateTime HexToDateTime(String hexDate)
{
    long intDate = long.Parse(hexDate, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    DateTime date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddMilliseconds(intDate);

    return date;
}
```

Error : Um namespace não pode conter diretamente membros, como campos ou métodos.

Comment: Esse é o código completo?

Comment: @Maury Developer só o método com problema. Devo colocar o código inteiro ?

Comment: Não, só era uma dúvida.

Comment: Sobre o erro: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0116 Pergunta parecida: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/373527/cs0116-c-um-namespace-não-pode-conter-diretamente-membros-como-campos-ou-métod

Comment: pelo erro vc deve ter colocado o método direto após o namespace, um método deve estar dentro de uma classe, verifique a estrutura do seu código

Comment: Tudo dentro de um projeto deve estar contido numa classe. Visto, talvez esse seja o problema. Envolva seus métodos, propriedades e variáveis todas em uma classe. De: Augusto Henrique

Comment: Ele realmente estava fora da classe. Obrigado pelo tempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tudo dentro de um projeto deve estar contido numa classe. Visto, talvez esse seja o problema. Envolva seus métodos, propriedades e variáveis todas em uma classe. De: Augusto Henrique

O exemplo a seguir fará com que o Visual Studio sinalize partes do código como em violação a CS0116. A tentativa de compilação desse código resultará em falha na compilação:

```cs
// CS0116.cs
namespace x
{
    // A namespace can be placed within another namespace
    using System;

    // These variables trigger the CS0116 error as they are declared outside of a struct or class
    public int latitude;
    public int longitude;
    Coordinate coord;

    // Autoproperties also fall under the definition of this rule
    public string LocationName { get; set; } 

    // This method as well: if it isn't in a class or a struct, it's violating CS0116
    public void DisplayLatitude()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Lat: {latitude}");
    }

    public struct Coordinate 
    {

    }

    public class CoordinatePrinter
    {
        public void DisplayLongitude()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Longitude: {longitude}");
        }

        public void DisplayLocation()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Location: {LocationName}");
        }
    }
}
```

Observe que, em C#, métodos e variáveis devem ser declarados e definidos dentro de uma classe ou struct. Para saber mais sobre a estrutura do programa em C#, consulte o artigo Estrutura geral de um programa em C#. Para corrigir esse erro, reescreva o código de modo que todos os métodos e campos estejam contidos dentro de um struct ou classe:

```cs
namespace x
{
    // A namespace can be placed within another namespace
    using System;     

    // These variables are now placed within a struct, so CS0116 is no longer violated
    public struct Coordinate
    {
        public int Latitude;
        public int Longitude;
    }

    // The methods and fields are now placed within a class, and the compiler is satisfied
    public class CoordinatePrinter
    {
        Coordinate coord;
        public string LocationName { get; set; }

        public void DisplayLatitude()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Lat: {coord.Latitude}");
        }

        public void DisplayLongitude()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Longitude: {coord.Longitude}");
        }

        public void DisplayLocation()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Location: {LocationName}");
        }
    }
}
```

Sobre o erro:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0116

Pergunta parecida:
[CS0116 C# Um namespace não pode conter diretamente membros, como campos ou métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/373527/cs0116-c-um-namespace-n%C3%A3o-pode-conter-diretamente-membros-como-campos-ou-m%C3%A9tod)